# Is this phrase technobabble or can it be broken down to be understandable?

Tags: internal-consistency, nanotechnology

I came across this term as a sci-fi novum but the source didn't really explain what it meant. It's Tissue Nanotransfection and I don't know if I should dismiss it as technobabble or if I can use it for my sci fi world. Breaking it down; what would it mean? I know it has something to do with medical nanotechnology but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: First off, this question is off-topic for this site, so I'm voting to close it. Second, transfection is a real term for sticking DNA or RNA into a cell. So a nanotransfection would probably be using a miniature robot to do the sticking. The word tissue added on...that doesn't really make any sense, to me at least. This question might be on-topic at biology, but I sort of doubt it. In any case, just google 'transfection.'

Comment: Google it up, like I just did.  Here is the first of many hits.  https://medicine.osu.edu/regenerativemedicine/pressandrecognition/tissue%20nanotransfection/pages/index.aspx

Comment: @kingledion, I wouldn't be surprised if the source added "tissue" for the same reason my wife's shampoo added the word "moisturizing" to "humectant" (as in "humectant moisturizing").  To either (a) make an incomprehensible technical term no one would take the time to look up sensible or (b) to improve their marketing.  "Humectant" means "to retain moisture."  AKA, moisturizing.  (And you can thank the department of redundancy department for that!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, it's a real scientific technique. I know it does sound like technobabble, but it's for real.

> Researchers have developed a device that can switch cell function to rescue failing body functions with a single touch. The technology, known as Tissue Nanotransfection (TNT), injects genetic code into skin cells, turning those skin cells into other types of cells required for treating diseased conditions.

Source:  [Ohio State University Wexner Medical Center](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/08/170807120530.htm) Dateline: 7 August 2017.

Comment: Somehow I feel they just wanted to make "TNT"...

Comment: @VilleNiemi I got a bang out of your TNT comment. This is the trouble with acronyms. Too many multiple word names of things have the same acronyms. I remember there is a molecule called ESP, the part I can't remember is its full name or chemical composition, which is the same acronym as 'extrasensory perception'.,